# Infinite while loop with break statement

Tags: java, android, loops, infinite-loop

I am a beginner and I was analyzing this java code:

```
// t is a thread running
while (true) {
    try {
        t.join(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    break;
}
t=null;
```

What I am asking is: is there a need to put that inside an infinite loop? Because as I see the loop will run only once i.e due to that break statement. I need some explanation please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no need. Your observation is correct, the loop will be executed only once.

**So the OP-posted code is equivalent to the following code.**

```
// t is a thread running
try {
    t.join(); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
t=null;
```

**Code posted by OP:**

```
// t is a thread running
while (true) {
    try {
        t.join(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    break;
}
t=null;
```

Comment: The break is in the wrong place, but it *is* necessary.  See my answer, below

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike If the break (in the original code) was right after the t.join() call, then of course, I agree with you. I was also looking for such subtleties and boundary cases before answering. But the break was not there and so I answered the original question, taking into account the original code. And when looking at the original code, I still think it is absolutely equivalent to the code which I posted.

Comment: Definitely. Totally agree.  As I say, though, that code is buggy because t can be set null before the thread it references, ends.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has already pointed out, the code is incorrect as it stands.

**The loop, however *is* necessary**!

The correct code looks like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        t.join();
        break; 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
t = null;
```

Without the loop, it is possible for `t` to be set to null, *before* the current thread successfully joins it.

Comment: It is said that thread t is started, so execution is started. Therefore nothing happens another thread sets t to null.

Comment: Not true!  Thread t is clearly running!  It could interrupt the thread on which this code is running.  That interrupt would cause the join() to complete, prematurely and t would get set to null, before the thread completed.

Comment: Nothing happens t is set to be null while it is running. Run my code sample.

Comment: @Indika You are mistaken.  I'll say it one more time: join() can be terminated by an InterruptedException, even though thread t has not terminated.  If it does, t will be set to null before t exits.  The loop and the break are necessary.

Comment: You wrote: "as everyone has already pointed out, the code is incorrect as it stands"... Actually I don't think anyone understood the real intention of this code, I think we were all just commenting/answering on the existing code as it stands... I guess you observation about the actual intention of this code (which the OP posted) might be correct. So +1 for me about that.

Answer (score 0):

t.join(); waiting the finishing of thread.
After that, loop is broken by your "break".
=> always loop only 1 time => no need loop and break, only need t.join();

Answer (score 0):

No need to have a while loop, because t.join() waits for the thread to die. 
is like a loop already, in the program at the line of `t.join()` the program will be blocked while the thread is not dead.

The correct code is:

```
// t is a thread running
    try {
        t.join(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    t=null;
```

Here you have an example :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_join.htm

Comment: What's this `break;` for?

Comment: I forgot to remove it. Thank you.

Comment: The loop *is* necessary!

Answer (score 0):

**Loop is not necessary!.**
It is said that thread t is already started. Therefore it makes no sense "t=null". Thread t is already started and it will finish its job. You can use t.join() without while loop. In this context while loop does not make sense. The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,

t.join();

causes the current thread(main thread in below example) to pause execution until t's thread terminates.Run following code snippet and know the ropes.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t=new Thread(
         new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"--"+i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    t.start();

    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    t = null;  // no sense, t is already started

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"--Thread--"+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken.  The loop *is* necessary.